# Five persons, A, B, C, D, and E, are going to speak at a meeting

Tags: probability

Five persons, A, B, C, D, and E, are going to speak at a meeting.

a) In how many orders can they take their turns if B must speak after A?

b) How many if B must speak immediately after A?

***Heres what Ive got so far.***

**a)** A first: 24 ways (4!)B first: N/A C first: 12 ways

CA 3!, CB N/A, CD: CDA 2!, CDB N/A, CDEAB 1, CE: CEA 2!, CEB N/A, CEDAB 1

D first: 12 ways

E first: 12 ways . This gives a total of 72 ways

**b)** I have simply 4!

Its a bit messy but do I have it right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to a) is wrong, simply because you added the numbers up incorrectly.

Here's another way t do it. In half of all orders, A speaks before B. (B speaks before A in the other half.)

Your answer to b) is correct. The problem is the same as asking how many ways you can order C, D, E and a pretend letter "AB."

Comment: ugh that would've made it so much easier. thanks :)

Comment: Either A would speak former than B or B would speak former than A and so there is no inbetween case i.e. no intersection of both events so now if total number of ways for speaking is N then $$N=N(A)+N(B)=2N(A)$$ because both events of speaking former for A and B are equally likely then$$N/2=N(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

a.) A speaks first $4!=24$ ways ,
A speaks second :- Now put A fixed at second position and fill other positions before A and after A like this:-
Before A,$3 $ ways (either C,D or E) After A,$3!$ ways i.e Total number of ways$=3\times3!=18$

likewise for A speaks third:-$(3\times2)_{before}$$\times(2!)_{after}=12$ ways
A speaks fourth:-$(3\times2\times1)_{before}\times(1)_{after}=6$ ways

A can not speak fifth
So total number of ways =$$24+18+12+6=60$$

Your answer for b.)is correct